# ASP .Net Core Swagger UI IFormFile Does not work

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, iformfile

I added an upload method (HTTPPOST) to upload a simple file. I keep getting this error and don't know where it come from. Can someone explain it please?

And maybe is there someone who can answer this question as well, it's not the most important one, but can you pass a file extension filter to this operation filter? That it only accepts .csv for example? Or is that something we should later do in frontend as in backend check which extension it has when it is already uploading?

ERROR:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V47Yt.png)

Post Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public void Post(IFormFile file)
{
}
```

OperationFilter:

```
public class FormFileOperation : IOperationFilter
{
    private const string FormDataMimeType = "multipart/form-data";
    private static readonly string[] FormFilePropertyNames = typeof(IFormFile).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();

    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.Any(x => x.ModelMetadata.ContainerType == typeof(IFormFile)))
        {
            var formFileParameters = operation
                .Parameters
                .OfType<NonBodyParameter>()
                .Where(x => FormFilePropertyNames.Contains(x.Name))
                .ToArray();
            var index = operation.Parameters.IndexOf(formFileParameters.First());
            foreach (var formFileParameter in formFileParameters)
            {
                operation.Parameters.Remove(formFileParameter);
            }

            var formFileParameterName = context
                .ApiDescription
                .ActionDescriptor
                .Parameters
                .Where(x => x.ParameterType == typeof(IFormFile))
                .Select(x => x.Name)
                .First();
            var parameter = new NonBodyParameter()
            {
                Name = formFileParameterName,
                In = "formData",
                Description = "The file to upload.",
                Required = true,
                Type = "file"
            };
            operation.Parameters.Insert(index, parameter);

            if (!operation.Consumes.Contains(FormDataMimeType))
            {
                operation.Consumes.Add(FormDataMimeType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with swagger. swagger is specification not implementation.
one-way I would do is stop accepting any other file extension.

This is pseudo code you will need to change and compile it.

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
{
   files = Request.Files;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
       if(!file.FileName.EndWith('.csv'))
       continue;

       Save/UploadFile
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

I would not over engineer it more then that for file upload.

Comment: For the file extensions it is just what i thought, i was just wondering.
For the IFormFile use i am not helped with this...